# Раздельный вывод звука с разных программ по каналам R и L через Alsa

Tags: linux, аудио, alsa

Можно ли разделить вывод звука от разных программ (А и Б) , работающих одновременно  по аудиоканалам L и R, соответственно, с одной звуковой картой на устройстве Linux (armbian ubuntu), например (Nano pi, orange pi, raspberry pi) через конфиг файл asound.config?

Answer (score 1):

Если не жалеть процессорных тактов (и железка потянет), то я бы сделал как-то так:

```
pcm.left {
  @args [ SLAVE ]
  @args.SLAVE {
      type string default "default"
  }
  type route
  slave.pcm $SLAVE
  ttable {
    0.0 1
    1.0 1
  }
}

pcm.right {
  @args [ SLAVE ]
  @args.SLAVE {
      type string default "default"
  }
  type route
  slave.pcm $SLAVE
  ttable {
    0.1 1
    1.1 1
  }
}

pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave.pcm {
        @func getenv
        vars [ ALSA_PCM ]
        default "plug:dmix"
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
$ ALSA_PCM="left:plug:dmix"  ./A
$ ALSA_PCM="right:plug:dmix" ./B
```

Более эффективно можно это сделать, если вместо `dmix` использовать плагин `share` или `dshare`.

Comment: спасибо, уже решил)

Answer (score 0):

```
pcm.dmix_stream
{
    type dmix
    ipc_key 321456 
    ipc_key_add_uid true
    slave.pcm "hw:2,0"
}

pcm.ch1 {
    type plug
    slave {
        pcm dmix_stream 
        channels 2
    }
    ttable.0.0 1    
}

pcm.ch2 {
    type plug
    slave {
        pcm dmix_stream 
        channels 2
    }
    ttable.0.1 1    
}

pcm.!default
{
    type asym
    playback.pcm
    {
        type plug
        slave.pcm "ch1"
    }
    capture.pcm 
    {
        type plug
        slave.pcm "hw:2,0"
    }
}
```